# How to terminate my program if scanf fails (in C)?

Tags: c, scanf, program-entry-point

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int Set1PColour(char *P1Colour)
{
    char colour;
    do
    {
        printf("Please choose starting color (Y)ellow or (R)ed: ");
        if (scanf(" %c", &colour) != 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        *P1Colour = colour;
    } while ((colour != 'R') && (colour != 'Y'));
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char P1Colour;
    if (Set1PColour(&P1Colour) == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nzero was not returned.");

    return 1;
}
```

My goal for my program is to terminate it if scanf fails in a function.

How do I make sure the program ends without printing "Zero was not returned"?

Basically I was expecting the program to end on this line  once I enter a value like 4.5, but it just continues.

```c
if (Set1PColour(&P1Colour) == 1)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, you could call `exit` but it's kinda bad behavior to do that in a function just because someone gave an invalid response.

Comment: On an unrelated note, there's really no need for the `colour` variable. You could use `P1Colour` directly in `scanf` as `scanf(" %c",P1Colour)`

Comment: Under what circumstances will `scanf` fail with `%c` format specifier? Only at EOF.

Comment: Entering `4.5` won't make `scanf()` fail in your code.

Comment: Regarding that `4.5` input. All three of the characters in that input are *characters* and will be successfully read by the "read *character* format specifier" `%c`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `isdigit()` - https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit

Comment: ...or at `!isalpha(colour)`. But I don't see the point – you've checked for required characters anyway. The only use I can make sense of is to check for the <Esc> key. It's rather brutal to quit the program when an entry is mis-typed.

Comment: OT: you should format your code properly, for example like the samples in your learning material. Your code is unreadable.